# Keeping connection to PubNub open

Tags: .net, push-notification, pubnub

I'm using the PubNub .net dll, to get notification only from new events (I'm not sending anything back), it works great for a while, but then the events are not coming in anymore. until I restart the application.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, do I need to refresh the connection every while?

Here's the code I use to subscribe:

```
            Pubnub = New Pubnub(publishKey:="", subscribeKey:="<myKeyHere>")
            Pubnub.SessionUUID = "<publishKey>"
            Pubnub.AuthenticationKey = "<auth>"
            channel = "<channel>"

            Pubnub.Subscribe(Of String)(channel, AddressOf userCallback,
                                 AddressOf connectCallback, AddressOf DisplayErrorMessage)
```

Comment: I sent it via email to support[at]pubnub.com since its too large to post here.

Comment: thank you for your detailed submission.  Your account assistant today is Craig Conover @ PubNub.

Comment: Ezi, just doing some follow up and wondering if we did resolve your issue in support.

Comment: It was never resolved. I came to the conclusion that pubNub cannot work on winForms for long periods without any activity, it gets to sleep and never wake up.. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please contact us at support@pubnub.com directly so we can fix this issue for you, it should never happen.

Comment: Sounds like a issue with winForms. Something must be causing the connection to end. More details would be helpful. Did you ever contact PubNub support?